# Accumulated sum with Find

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with code that takes some values from one column and makes subtotals. This cells are not ever the same, so i'have used .Find for locate them. once they are selected, the aim is sum them and place the result in other cell column, designated for having these subtotals. I'have made my macro using accumulators, the problem is i cannot find a way of avoiding the sum of those subtotals as well. May somebody help please?
For explanation i've included this pic. Red arrows are the accumulation i would like to avoid.
Thanks to all!

[Codification & accumulates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJHQA.jpg)

Code used:

```
    Sub Mod9x()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim arr As Variant, arrElem1 As Variant, arrElem2 As Variant, arrElem3 As Variant
    Dim sumtotal As Variant
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Subtotal = 0
    subs = 0
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Valeurs")
    lr = sh1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        With Worksheets("Valeurs")
        For i = 15 To lr
            For Each cell In sh1.Cells(i, 5)

            arr = Split(Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " "), " ")
                    For Each arrElem1 In arr
                        If Len(arrElem1) = 22 Then
                        lResult1 = Left(arrElem1, Len(arrElem1) - 8)
                            Set findv1 = Range("E15:E3000").Cells.Find(What:=lResult1, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            after:=Range("E15"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                            findv1.Offset(, 16).Select

                                         With Selection.Interior
                                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
                                        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
                                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                                        End With

                            lResult2 = arrElem1

                            Set findv2 = Range("E15:E3000").Cells.Find(What:=lResult2, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            after:=Range("E15"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

                            If findv2.Offset(, 1) <> "" And findv2.Offset(, 2) <> "" And findv2.Offset(, 10) <> "" Then

                                findv2.Offset(, 15).Select
                                Subtotal = Subtotal + findv2.Offset(, 15)
                                findv1.Offset(, 16) = Subtotal

                                Set findco = Range("E15:E3000").Cells.Find(What:=findv1, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                after:=findv1, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

                                        With Selection.Interior
                                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                                        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
                                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                                        End With

                            End If
                        End If
                 Next arrElem1
            Next cell
          Next i
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What distinguishes the subtotals you want from those that you don't want?

Comment: Hi SJR, a codification method. You could see it on pic added (codification...). These code are in one column. according they places, it will give totals or subtotals. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear how your two pictures relate. Are you trying to sum some of the green values in the right-hand column and exclude some green values? If that is based on the text values in the second images that would appear to be the basis for your code, but I can't say I fully undersand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok SJR, please see pic **Codification & accumulates**, perhaps this time it is better shown. Thanks so much!

Comment: So are the values you need the ones with GC_TRN_ and then four sets of numbers separated by underscores?

Comment: Yes SJR,  i need the sum of those numbers with **four sets**, totalized on cells with **three sets**. The code here almost achieves that, the problem is as you can see, it accumulates also the "three sets" cells.

Comment: Try using the `Split` function using underscore as the delimiter. The upper bound will be 5 if there are four sets as it's zero-based. Does that make sense? Also, for your current code, read up on how to avoid Select.

Comment: Would you mind please SJR give some example (code). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following on from comments, a simple scenario with your text in column A and numbers in column B, this will find the values in A with four underscores and cumulatively add the results in column C.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, d As Double

For Each r In Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If UBound(Split(r, "_")) = 5 Then
        d = d + r.Offset(, 1).Value
        r.Offset(, 2).Value = d
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```